# Share a reactive variable between client and server

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor, how may I share a reactive variable between the client and the server?

It is one number, so I do not wish to use mongodb / collections.

EDIT: To be clear I mean don't wish to use a mongodb collection to share a single number, not that I will be trying to avoid it in general.

Comment: AFAIK change events are generated at the MongoDB side and passes them to the server and then the client. You might want to try meteor + redis if you don't want to use mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If you want to use reactive var package specifically, this might help https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/.

You could use a session var which would be more easy to implement and would suffice for your requirements I think. Check this out if you need intro to sessions, http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/sessions/

To share the session var between client and server, you could use something like on the client

```
Meteor.Subscribe('xyz', Session.get('id'));
```

and this on the server

```
Meteor.publish('xyz', function (id) {
...
});
```

Comment: Am I not correct in thinking that you can't update session variables from the server side?

Comment: One could use this for that part https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-server-session/, it uses the same kind of api

Comment: Well till, Meteor 0.6 I think, session var were available natively both on the client and server side but things changed after that.

Comment: Also, it appears that the ServerSession is only available to the server?